# JDK 1.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: java

I want to install JDK 1.2 to compile my legacy project.
I can't upgrade to latest JDK because of so many limitations. I downloaded it from [Sun website](http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/install-linux-136607.html) and followed all the steps given in the linked page.

When I run `javac -version` I get the following error message:

```
$ /usr/local/jdk1.2.2/bin/javac -version
Error: can't find libjava.so
```

I installed my JDK in `/usr/local/jdk1.2.2` location.
(I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit).
Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your specific reason for using Java 1.2?  Java is generally backwards-compatible at both a source and binary level.

Comment: I Just want to limit my self to use only APIs of 1.2 or below in my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I understand that there might be different reasons for using a specific version, but if you are using JDK 1.2 only because source code is Java 1.2 compatible, I think you can use `-source` (and / or `-target`) switch of latest JDK's javac to inform the source code compatibility.

For more information, please visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 3):

This is the same issue with installing jdk1.3.1 on newer system. Since uname -m returns x86_64, you have to add that option to some of the scripts:

```
/bin/.java_wrapper
/jre/bin/.java_wrapper
/jre/bin/realpath
```

add x86_64 as on of the cases for the i386 option
example:

```
case "`uname -m`" in
    i[3-6]86  | ia32 | ia64 | i?86 | x86_64)
        proc=i386
        ;;
```

Just add "| x86_64" to the case statement at the top of each file.

At this point when you run java -version you will get a "Segmentation fault." I'm still not sure how to fix this...

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to resolve the segmentation fault error?

Comment: No, I gave up on it after a while. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The java executable is not able to find the `libjava.so` shared library:

Check if you have a `libjava.so` file in your installation

```
$ find /usr/local/jdk1.2.2/ -name libjava.so
```

If not your installation is broken (and without any details it will be difficult to help you)

If the file is there you can try to add the directory where the file is located to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.2.2/PATH_WHERE_LIBJAVA_SO_IS_LOCATED:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thank for your help.
I found libjava in "jdk1.2.2/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so" location
and updated LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 
    $echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
    /usr/local/jdk1.2.2/jre/lib/i386/libjava.so:

Even then I am getting same problem.

    $/usr/local/jdk1.2.2/bin/javac -version
    Error: can't find libjava.so

Btw installation is not broken(it is simple extraction for tar file).

Comment: Ok now I see, I don't think it will work with your 64 bit environment. Would "Garbage"'s solution work for you?

Comment: And yes Mr Garbage's solution worked for me. I Just want to limit my self to use only API of 1.2 or below in my IDE.